# Getting interpolated colors from GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

So I'm trying to modify my current shaders to allow me to get interpolation between the vertexes. The setup I have now is only allowing me to define the color per triangle and I believe that this is because I am setting the color in the Fragment shader instead of the Vertex shader.

Code:

```
GLuint MakeSphereShader ()
{
    const GLchar* _vertexShaderCode = "\
     #version 130\n                                                                                                     \
     in vec4 Position;                                                                                                  \
     in vec4 Normal;                                                                                                        \
     uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;                                                                                          \
     uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;                                                                                           \
     uniform mat4 PerspectiveMatrix;                                                                                        \
     uniform mat4 Rotations;                                                                                                \
     uniform vec4 Light;                                                                                                    \
     uniform float Red;                                                                                                 \
     uniform float Green;                                                                                               \
     uniform float Blue;                                                                                                    \
     out vec3 NormalVector;                                                                                             \
     out vec3 LightVector;                                                                                              \
     out vec4 ColorVector;                                                                                              \
     void main () {                                                                                                     \
        NormalVector = (Rotations*Normal).xyz;                                                                          \
        LightVector = Light.xyz;                                                                                        \
        gl_Position = PerspectiveMatrix*ViewMatrix*ModelMatrix*Position;                                                \
        ColorVector = vec4(Red, Green, Blue, 1.0);                                                                      \
    }";
    const GLchar* _fragmentShaderCode = "\
        #version 130\n                                                                                                      \
        in vec3 NormalVector;                                                                                               \
        in vec3 LightVector;                                                                                                \
        in vec3 ColorVector;                                                                                                \
        uniform bool Lighting;                                                                                              \
        out vec4 Color;                                                                                                     \
        void main () {                                                                                                      \
            vec3 _normal = normalize(NormalVector);                                                                         \
            vec3 _light = normalize(LightVector);                                                                           \
            float _diffuseIntensity = max(abs(dot(_normal, _light)), 0.1);                                                  \
            float _alpha = 0.4;                                                                                             \
            if (!Lighting)                                                                                                  \
            {                                                                                                               \
                _diffuseIntensity = 1.0;                                                                                    \
                _alpha = 0.6;                                                                                               \
            }                                                                                                               \
            Color = vec4(_diffuseIntensity/5 + ColorVector[0], _diffuseIntensity/5 + ColorVector[1], _diffuseIntensity/5 + ColorVector[2], _alpha);     \
        }";
    GLuint _vertShaderID = makeVertexShader(_vertexShaderCode);
    GLuint _fragShaderID = makeFragmentShader(_fragmentShaderCode);
    return makeShaderProgram(_vertShaderID, _fragShaderID);
    }
```

So what I've been doing before was drawing like so:

```
glUniform1f(glMatrices.RedID, _red);
glUniform1f(glMatrices.GreenID, _green);
glUniform1f(glMatrices.BlueID, _blue);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (k=0; k<3; k++) 
    {
        glVertexAttrib3d(glMatrices.PositionID, _x[k], _y[k], _z[k]);
        glVertexAttrib3d(glMatrices.NormalID, _unitv.X, _unitv.Y, _unitv.Z);
    }
glEnd();
```

So it makes sense that if I tell the fragment shader the color to use it will color every pixel the color I specified. So I've been trying to move the color variables to the vertex shader but I'm not positive what the correct way to do that is. I was working on this before and got it to work but only on my Nvidia machine and not on an ATI so I must have been abusing some rule I didn't know I was doing.

I've tried adding `out vec4 ColorVector` to the vertex shader and sending that to the fragment but is starts throwing invalid value and crashes.

What is the proper way to define color per vertex and not per triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normal needs to come before the position. When you use immediate mode, declaring vertex attribute **0** is what finalizes a vertex. Though you have not shown the code where you bind attribute locations, I have to assume that position is bound to **0**, otherwise you would see nothing on screen.

Right now, the only source of color in this entire shader is from a uniform (constant). Your colors are not per-vertex or even per-triangle, they are per-program. Interpolation will not change anything when every vertex you process has the same input color.

#### You need to use a per-vertex attribute for this to work:

```c
in vec4 Color;

...

ColorVector = Color;
```

#### Then your drawing code will look something like this:

```c
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (k=0; k<3; k++) 
    {
        glVertexAttrib3d(glMatrices.NormalID,   _unitv.X, _unitv.Y, _unitv.Z);
        glVertexAttrib3f(glMatrices.ColorID,    _red,     _green,   _blue);
        glVertexAttrib3d(glMatrices.PositionID, _x[k],    _y[k],    _z[k]);
    }
glEnd();
```

The color is still constant of course, I will leave that up to you to figure out how to fix. But this does let you pass a unique color per-vertex once you figure that out.

Comment: So that worked wonderfully on my Nvidia machine but the ATI one is having some issues, I'm pretty positive it is because I am not binding attribute locations `PositionID = glGetAttribLocation(ShaderProgramID, "Position");` I assume this means that I'm letting openGl set them itself and this would cause the confusion on the ATI machine when it doesn't set position to 0. I suspect this because I can see vertexes attached to each other that shouldn't be

Comment: So should I be using `glBindAttribLocation` with the color, normal and color attributes? and is that instead of `glGetAttribLocation`?

Comment: This was the solution, 'glBindAttribLocation' for the position variable eliminated the confusion on the ATI machine. Thanks for the guidance Andon!